# How to animate Constraints?

Tags: animation, armature, constraints, parent

I am making a Reloading animation and I want at first to Parent the *mag* to the *gun* when it moves, then Parent the *mag* to the *hand*.

So to do that I though of creating 2 **Child of Constraints** and then somehow animate the disabling and enabling of the two *Constraints*.

So, how do I do that, if there is any way?

or maybe it would better be to do so somehow else.

& *please no python*

Comment: Did you tried to animate the **influence** sliders?

Comment: No sure, what you mean... Oh now I got it, but I want to change the parent of the mag Completely, from the bone of the gun to the bone of the hand

Comment: Maybe the best thing for me to do is to create a bone for the gun and then just with One Constraint, just animate the Bone that the mag is parented to by changing from gun bone to hand bone

Comment: Well, if you put two "child of" constraints to the mag, one linked to the gun, and another linked to the hand, you can animate their influences so that when the first is at 1, the other is at 0, and vice-versa. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I totaly got you now, yes thats what I mean,but will that mean that I will have to create a separate bone for the gun, as I need the mag to be parented to it at first

Comment: I don't know, haven't seen you setup, but if your gun has an armature, then I guess yes, you should parent the mag to the gun's bone. If not, you can "child of" anything to an object, or a bone (if the object is an armature). There is no rule about how to do that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27567/discussion-between-igor-tatarnikov-and-polosson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a better way to do what you want, but to answer your particular question about animating *child of* constraint, you can use the **influence** slider of each constraint.

Constraint the mag with two "child of" constraints, one linked to the gun, and another linked to the hand. Then you can animate their influences so that when the first is at 1, the other is at 0, and vice-versa.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of something like this, but with a twist - using two empties that are parented to the gun and hand each, so that one can readjust the positioning later without hassle just by nudging the empties. Also I was thinking of using Copy Transforms, but is there some benefit of using Child Of instead?

Comment: @Polosson  I didn't know this was even an option, and have needed this exact thing for sooooo long. Thanks for posting this answer. It will help simplify some of the work I do.