# How to make a model hold a gun?

Tags: rigging

How do I make a character hold a gun? At the same time, if I want to have a cutscene where one person is holding the gun and gives it to another, how would I do something like that?

Comment: Look into the Child Of constraint: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html

Comment: BornCG has several tutorials about this here is the link https://www.youtube.com/user/cgboorman

Comment: You animate the [influence of the constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36735/935) to switch it from one person to the other.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll have to look into those.